# How can I generate AWS SES SMTP credentials using the CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-cdk

There is a manual on how to obtain SMTP credentials using GUI:

[Obtaining Amazon SES SMTP credentials using the Amazon SES console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html)

Is there a way to achieve this using Amazon CDK? So far, I've tried using `aws-ses` package with zero luck.

I don't expect you to write the code for me, just point me to the right direction.

Describing a workflow will do just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining Amazon SES SMTP credentials requires the below IAM policies per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html):

> Your IAM policy must allow you to perform the following IAM actions: `iam:ListUsers`, `iam:CreateUser`, `iam:CreateAccessKey`, and `iam:PutUserPolicy`.

What happens behind the GUI is:

1. An IAM user name is either inputted (and validated using `iam:ListUsers`) or is created (using `iam:CreateUser`)
2. An inline policy is added to the user's permissions (using `iam:PutUserPolicy`) to grant them access to perform `ses:SendRawEmail`:

> `"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":"ses:SendRawEmail","Resource":"*"}]`

3. SMTP credentials are then generated for the above user (using `iam:CreateAccessKey`)

**You essentially need to do the above using the [`@aws-cdk/aws-iam`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html) module, not the `@aws-cdk/aws-ses` module (as that's for actually using SES).**

---

For extra confirmation, here's the AWS console mentioning the above:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not answer how to generate SMTP credentials in CDK as far as I see.

First you need to create an IAM User and a CfnAccessKey for this user.
Then the SMTP password needs to be generated from the Secret Access Key as documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/smtp-credentials.html#smtp-credentials-convert

As far as I see the only way to do this in CDK is by using a CustomResource.
An example of such an implementation can be found here:
https://github.com/binxio/cfn-secret-provider/blob/master/src/cfn_accesskey_provider.py

However, as also mentioned in the README (https://github.com/isotoma/ses-smtp-credentials-cdk#nota-bene-confidentiality-of-keys),
the STMP password should not be returned from the CustomResource, but instead stored as a Secret.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using this library: https://github.com/pepperize/cdk-ses-smtp-credentials

Install with `npm install @pepperize/cdk-ses-smtp-credentials`

You can then use this in your CDK stack:

```js
import { User } from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam";
import { SesSmtpCredentials } from "@pepperize/cdk-ses-smtp-credentials";

const smtpCredentials = new SesSmtpCredentials(this, "SmtpCredentials", {
  userName: "ses-user",
});

// smtpCredentials.secret contains json value {username: "<the generated access key id>", password: "<the calculated ses smtp password>"}
```